# Understanding common collector amplfier for a piezoelectric microphone

Tags: transistors

I copied the circuit of a Throat Microphone that uses piezoelectric disk to detect vibrations. I'm trying to adapt to detect vibrations (i.e door knocks, etc) but the signal is weak when I record the audio using Audacity. I'm trying to understand the circuit to be able to adjust the gain according to the type of vibrations to be recorded. Using an oscilloscope, the weakest vibration measured around 100mV and the highest averaged around 600mV with peaks of 1V.

[image: Schematic]

So far, I found that the amplifier is arranged as a Common Collector and \$ R_{1} \$ and \$ R_{2} \$ expecting around 1V (I found in a post that the microphone port supplies 1.5V-2.5V) and lowering \$ R_{3} \$ increases \$ I_{c} \$ and the gain. I'm not sure if I'm going on the right way and I would appreciate some hints.

The NPN transistor is 833-2SC1623-L6-TP.

$$ \begin{align} 470\Omega &= \frac{V_{cc} - 0.5 V_{cc}}{I_{c}} \\
&= \frac{0.5 \cdot V_{cc}}{0.001} = 940 mV \\
Gain &= \frac{R_c}{R_e} \\ 
&= \frac{470}{26} = 18 \\
&= \frac{470}{100+26} = 3.73 \\
V_{b} &= V_{e} + 0.6V \\ 
&= .032 + 0.6 = 0.63
\end{align}
 $$

Comment: Where did you find the schematic? (It seems weird to consider a BJT for a piezo input. I'd imagine more like a JFET _plus_ a BJT.)

Comment: I disassembled a throat microphone from Amazon (similar to https://www.amazon.com/Braudel-Adjustable-Microphone-Anti-noise-Hands-free/dp/B0112186UG/ ). I'd consider building something better but my knowledge of electronics is kind of limited.

Comment: I'm just worried about the impedance. A piezo doesn't have much current compliance. The jfet would seem to match that better, but may need some help with voltage gain. But I haven't tried to do a design. I was curious about where that came from, as perhaps I could see how they thought about the problem.

Comment: I didn't thought about that. I'm going to ask my professor for additional help but If I'm getting the information correctly from what I read, the JFET works as a buffer for the input and I use a BJT to control the gain?

Comment: Aside from loading the piezo, BJTs driven by high source impedances need to be run with very low collector currents, but even then the noise figure goes to heck. JFETs _then_ give better noise performance than BJTs. But JFETs have low transconductance and crappy \$V_{GS}\$ matching besides. So you are back to wanting that BJT afterwards. That's why I said what I said, earlier. I'm just a hobbyist though. Your professor should know better than me about this.

Comment: Noise for high source resistances follows Johnson noise. High noise goes with high resistance. Then BJT shot noise follows \$I_C\$. So you want to lower that. But a JFET doesn't have much shot noise since it derives from leakage current, which can be very small, and much smaller than the signal current in the BJT. So that's a reason why the JFET is nice at times like this. It has a niche.

Answer (score 1):

> I found that the amplifier is arranged as a Common Collector

That would be incorrect - it's a common emitter. Connect "pad 4" to ground and use an external pull-up resistor from "out" to some supply voltage (maybe 6 volts to 12 volts) and that junction labelled "out" is an output that feeds into an amplifier.

The value of the pull-up resistor sets the gain - if it were 1 kohm then the gain would be ten - the ratio of collector pull-up resistor to emitter resistor (100 ohm) sets the gain. The 470R is just there to limit too much current into the circuit should you choose an external pull-up that is too low.

Comment: Neglecting the transconductance gm (resp. re=1/gm=26 Ohms) causes a computational gain error of 25 % if the emitter resistor is 100 Ohms (as in the present case).

Answer (score 1):

it is a common emitter amplifier.

piezo sensors are of high output impedance and it would be illogical to put them on a common collector amplifier (low input impedance).

the signal is applied to the base, and the gain will dependent on the load from the OUT pin to Vcc.

< lowering R_{3} increases I_{c} and the gain.

only to some extent. the typical hFE curve for a bjt goes up with Ic and then goes down.